# PHP error logging to file, with display_errors OFF

Tags: apache-2.2, php.ini

In my PHP.ini, I have it set to log errors to a file, and display_errors is OFF.

However, my errors are NEVER being logged... anyone know what common issues are, or what could be preventing them from being logged?

There's definitely no overwritting issues in my code (I wrote the code, and I've never changed anything related to errors via the code...).

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Be sure you modify the proper php.ini file (this may sound silly but I've had this problem many times). `phpinfo()` is your friend here to tell you which `ini` file is used.
- Be sure the folder where the log file should be written is writable
- Post your configuration (don't forget to hide secure information) and which OS you run.

Comment: Also check what your error_reporting levels are.  Set them low enough and you'll never report an error...

Comment: You may have said "**if** you set them too low you'll never report an error" because if some foreign people like me read you answer it might be confusing ("set them" = could be and advice to do so).